# Camera getting stuck in the middle of animation

Tags: animation, camera

So I've made a triangle loopy design and now I'm passing my camera through it to complete my animation. It's a fairly long but completely straight design. Now i have keyframed my camera on either ends of the loop. The camera now starts moving straight then halfway through it suddenly bumps, falls back a little bit and stops. It restarts again and instantly the same action is repeated until the animation time runs out.
Note: i was seeing a reference tutorial of it and nothing such happened in that so i believe it's something in my settings. [image]

Comment: Please share a screenshot (not a photo) of your camera action (animation in Dope Sheet)

Comment: Check the Fcurves Camera Action .It will show if there is anything not as intended.